# A problem on adiabatic process

Tags: homework-and-exercises, thermodynamics, pressure, adiabatic

[image: The Question:]

I solved this using the relation PV^gamma = constant (since it's an adiabatic process) and solved for the ratio of volumes. The answer key has, however, proceeded with delta U + delta Q = 0. The answer is different from the former method's.

Why can't the first method be applied here?

Comment: You're asking the question in the vwrong way :/. Isolate the concept and ask, don't ask which way is right and why way is wrong. Study the method of solution, see what is the concept behind it, and then see how your concept is different from theres, or, if they are equivalent

Comment: Hint: You can't use $PV^{\gamma}$= constant because that is for a quasi-static reversible ideal gas process, which this isn't because the gas is rapidly compressed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem statement has a misleading phrase in it "without changing the ambient temperature."  This does not mean that temperature inside the cylinder does not change; it does.  In addition, the equation in the answer key is wrong.  It should read $$\Delta U=-W=-3P_0(V-V_0)$$where W is the work that the gas does on the surroundings,  compressing at the constant external pressure $3P_0$.  The equation tells us that $$nC_V(T-T_0)=-3P_0(V-V_0)$$or$$\frac{C_v}{R}(3P_0V-P_0V_0)-3P_0(V-V_0)$$